# Regex replace text between quotes and a little more

Tags: regex, regex-negation, octobercms

I'm using a new framework, OctoberCMS which has a  system for linking pages with twig.  This is an example of how it works

```
<a href="{{ '/about-us'|app }}">About Us</a>
```

I have a huge table with loads of links inside the cells and need to change the link format to one that complies with october's.

Here's an example link in the table cells:

```
<a href="/assets/Lecture%20Documents/MBCS/MBS%20Class%20Review.doc">Lecture Notes</a>
```

This is the format that it has to follow

```
<a href=
"/assets/<...long_path_to_file...>"> </a>
```

TO

```
<a href=
"{{ 'assets/<...long_path_to_file...>' |theme }}"> </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

match:

```
/href=("|')(.*)("|')/ig
```

and replace with

```
'href="{{ \'$2\'|theme }}"'
```

In javascript this would look like:

```
var a = // get anchor tag
a.replace(/href=("|')(.*)("|')/ig, 'href="{{ \'$2\'|theme }}"');
```

in php:

```
$htmlString = // get html string
$newHtml = preg_replace('/href=("|')(.*)("|')/ig', 'href="{{ \'$2\'|theme }}"', $htmlString);
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up changing a little bit to fit my requirements and here's the final regex
`/href=([^"]*)("|')(.assets)(.*)("|')/ig`